# Unity-bar fails to show randomly when using mouse?

Tags: unity, launcher, mouse, 13.04

### Description of my problem:

I have set Unity bar in 13.04 to auto-hide when not used under apperance settings. Sometimes, for example when using other programs (no matter what program) - it fails to show again, when i am moving my mouse into the top left corner. This is working sometimes, and sometimes it just doesn't work, and i have to click the dash-button in order to make it appear again. Well, and i have tried to set the sensitivity to other values, with no luck, and i have tried configuring CCSM to make it act normally - No luck.

## *Question:*

Can this issue be fixed, so the mouse reveal will work normally? Its even failing on the desktop sometimes. Same issues was found in earlier version, 12.10, but i chose not to bother about it.

*There was no duplicates found of this described problem*.